# Need help understanding "DBWinMutex"

Tags: windows, debugging, winapi

I am writing my own version of DebugView using this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23776/Mechanism-of-OutputDebugString as a starting point.
The code appears to work fine. However I do not understand the use of the named mutex  "DBWinMutex".
This mutex is opened at the beginning of the code:

```
CComBSTR DBWinMutex = L"DBWinMutex";
HANDLE m_hDBWinMutex = ::OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS,
                                   FALSE,
                                   DBWinMutex);
```

and not closed before the end of the program!?

I find this strange. I would think that the mutex would have to be locked and unlocked repeatedly so that OutputDebugString could write to the shared memory "DBWIN_BUFFER"?

However I am able to read OutputDebugString messages written by other programs so the mutex does not appear to lock "DBWIN_BUFFER" for writing.
Also I can also run DebugView in parallell with my DebugView implementation and they both can read OutputDebugString messages. So it seems the mutex does not grant exclusive read to "DBWIN_BUFFER" neither.

Using the MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS access as above means I have to run the program as administrator.
When I replace this with SYNCHRONIZE access the program appears to function exactly the same except that I do not have to run it as administrator.
Is this OK or may it cause some subtle bug?

Also I test the return from OpenMutex above and if it is null call CreateMutex.

Comment: `OpenMutex` returns a handle to a mutex. It does not acquire that mutex. Also, you don't need to check for `NULL` and then call `CreateMutex` if it is. Just use `CreateMutex`, which will either return a handle to an existing mutex object, or create a new one.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I acquire this mutex? WaitForSingleObject(mutex)? In the article I reference I do not see this handle being used at all.

Comment: `WaitForSingleObject` - yes, for acquire mutex

Comment: You don't need any mutex to capture the result of OutputDebugString, see here for a C version https://www.drdobbs.com/a-dbwin32-debugger-for-windows/184403245?pgno=3 and here for .NET https://github.com/smourier/TraceSpy/blob/master/TraceSpy/Main.cs or https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13345/DbMon-NET-A-simple-NET-OutputDebugString-capturer

Comment: @SimonMourier: thank you. But there exists a mutex named "DBWinMutex". What does this mutex do if it does not ensure that only one thread access  the "DBWIN_BUFFER" shared memory at a time?

Comment: I don't know what it does, you don't need this for OutputDebugString capture.

Comment: It synchronizes access to the shared memory used by `OutputDebugStringW`. It frequently works to just read that memory without acquiring access to it by way of the mutex that guards it. And it sometimes fails. .NET has a history of favoring features over safety. If you are looking to implement a robust solution, mimicking .NET isn't going to get you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [article you linked to](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23776/Mechanism-of-OutputDebugString), `DBWinMutex` is used only by `OutputDebugString()` itself, to prevent multiple threads from writing to the output buffer at the same time. It is not necessary for a debug monitor to use `DBWinMutex` at all:

[image]

However, there is a mistake in the above image.  It should look more like this instead:

[image]